# Make final decision based on four input decisions php

Tags: php, codeigniter, switch-statement

I am using CI framework PHP,

I want to make final decision results based on four users input decisions,

```
$this->input->post('decision_1', TRUE) == 0 //or 1 or 2 or 3
$this->input->post('decision_2', TRUE) == 0 //or 1 or 2 or 3
$this->input->post('decision_3', TRUE) == 0 //or 1 or 2 or 3
$this->input->post('decision_4', TRUE) == 0 //or 1 or 2 or 3
```

Now if any three inputs are same, then it will become final decision, or out of four or three inputs, maximum decisions will become final decision,

Example, if decision 1,2,3 are 0, then final should be 0
but if decision 1,2 are 0 and decision 4 is 1, then final should also be 1.

I tried with switch statement, but it did worked if all minimum 3 inputs are same, but if of three is different then i does not worked,

```
$result_case = TRUE;
      switch ($result_case) {
      case $this->input->post('decision_1', TRUE) == 1 && $this->input->post('decision_2', TRUE) == 1 && $this->input->post('decision_3', TRUE) == 1 :
          $result = 1;
          break;
      case $this->input->post('decision_1', TRUE) == 1 && $this->input->post('decision_2', TRUE) == 1 && $this->input->post('decision_4', TRUE) == 1 :
          $result = 1;
          break;
      case $this->input->post('decision_1', TRUE) == 1 && $this->input->post('decision_3', TRUE) == 1 && $this->input->post('decision_4', TRUE) == 1:
          $result = 1;
          break;
      case $this->input->post('decision_2', TRUE) == 1 && $this->input->post('decision_3', TRUE) == 1 && $this->input->post('decision_4', TRUE) == 1:
          $result = 1;
          break;
      //
      case $this->input->post('decision_1', TRUE) == 0 && $this->input->post('decision_2', TRUE) == 0 && $this->input->post('decision_3', TRUE) == 0:
          $result = 0;
          break;
      case $this->input->post('decision_1', TRUE) == 0 && $this->input->post('decision_2', TRUE) == 0 && $this->input->post('decision_4', TRUE) == 0:
          $result = 0;
          break;
      case $this->input->post('decision_1', TRUE) == 0 && $this->input->post('decision_3', TRUE) == 0 && $this->input->post('decision_4', TRUE) == 0:
          $result = 0;
          break;
      case $this->input->post('decision_2', TRUE) == 0 && $this->input->post('decision_3', TRUE) == 0 && $this->input->post('decision_4', TRUE) == 0:
          $result = 0;
          break;
      //
      case $this->input->post('decision_1', TRUE) == 2 && $this->input->post('decision_2', TRUE) == 2 && $this->input->post('decision_3', TRUE) == 2:
          $result = 2;
          break;
      case $this->input->post('decision_1', TRUE) == 2 && $this->input->post('decision_2', TRUE) == 2 && $this->input->post('decision_4', TRUE) == 2:
          $result = 2;
          break;
      case $this->input->post('decision_1', TRUE) == 2 && $this->input->post('decision_3', TRUE) == 2 && $this->input->post('decision_4', TRUE) == 2:
          $result = 2;
          break;
      case $this->input->post('decision_2', TRUE) == 2 && $this->input->post('decision_3', TRUE) == 2 && $this->input->post('decision_4', TRUE) == 2:
          $result = 2;
          break;

      default:
          $result = 'Undecided';
  }
```

Is there any easy way to check input decisions and make final one?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//save each post in as a key of an array.
$results[$this->input->post('decision_1', TRUE)][] = 1;
...
...
...
//count each type of the post
$results = array_map(function($v){return count($v);}, $results;);
$max = -1;
foreach($results as $k => $v)
{
  if($v >= 3)
    $result = $k;
  $max = $results[$max] > $v ? $max : $k;

}
//if a post type has more or equal to 3, chose it. otherwise chose the biggest key as the result.
$result = isset($result) ? $result : $max;
```

Comment: i got confused here, i have four input with three different possibilities,  so do i need to write 12 lines for $results[....], and you given if ($v >= 3), does this means that it will check minimum 3 inputs to get decision? I need final result if there are three decisions, otherwise default decision should be 3

Comment: you only have four input each time.  each user a desion. So each time the biggest is 4.

Comment: great, seems OK, just to ask one thing, if all 3 decisions are different, like 0,1,2....then i need to pass a default decision 3(undecided), how can i send default decision? In this case nothing is output as $result.

Comment: from the $results, you can get like this $decision3 = isset($results[3]) ? $results[3] : null;

Comment: can you explain me what is use of $max in foreach loop? as it is not used in $results calculation?

Comment: I make a mistake here. I've edited it. `$max` store the key of the biggest appearances of the desion